# Is it OK to use a single port for fast IPC communication?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

I am using async sockets and have a single IP address and port that my Server (Listener) and each (internal/ on machine) Client uses.

Every time new external data comes to the Server, it loops through its (internal) Clients and sends the data on via the same socket.

Might this cause a backlog? If I have 10 Clients will the last Client get his data considerably later than the first Client?

Is it possible to have Clients with different ports connecting to a single Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, think of how HTTP works -- it's always on port 80!  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example